# C++ - deleting a 2D array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i'm working in VC++, but this is a basic C++ question ... I am quite new with C++, never had to worry about deleting in Java ... Anyway, after some research, I believe I have found the right way to do a detele, but does not work ... I am using some temporary 2D arrays in a function, and before ending the function, I need to delete them. Here is the code:

```
int** a;
a = new int*[b/2];
for(int i = 0; i < (b/2); i++)
{
    a[i] = new int[b];

}

    // some code here. Not changing the b variable!

for(int i = 0; i < (b/2); i++)
{
    // error happens here
    delete[] a[i];
}
delete[] a;
```

After running the programm, I get a "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED" error - pasting the printscreen:
[image: Error Printscreen]

Any idea where could the problem be?

Thank you.

---

UPDATE

I am posting the debugger screenshot, happeng just before I get the error. (the variable a's real name is "vkljucenost":

[image: Debugger Screenshot]

---

UPDATE

Since some asked me to post more code, I am posting the whole function code:

```
int** CVaja3KruskalView::CalcKruskal(EnosSez* seznam, int dimenzijaMatr)
{
    int** rezultat; // results array
    int stRezultatov = 0; // number of connections
    rezultat = new int*[dimenzijaMatr-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < (dimenzijaMatr-1); i++)
    {
        rezultat[i] = new int[2]; // shranjujem p in q
        rezultat[i][0] = -1;
        rezultat[i][1] = -1;
    }

    int** vkljucenost;
    int* dolzVkljuc = new int[dimenzijaMatr/2]; // last list elements
    vkljucenost = new int*[dimenzijaMatr/2];
    for(int i = 0; i < (dimenzijaMatr/2); i++)
    {
        vkljucenost[i] = new int[dimenzijaMatr];
        dolzVkljuc[i] = -1; // the i-list is empty
    }

    EnosSez* tmp = seznam;
    int pVkljuc;
    int qVkljuc;
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        pVkljuc=Vkljuceno(vkljucenost, dolzVkljuc, tmp->p, dimenzijaMatr);
        qVkljuc=Vkljuceno(vkljucenost, dolzVkljuc, tmp->q, dimenzijaMatr);

        if(pVkljuc==qVkljuc && pVkljuc != -1) 
        {} else if (pVkljuc!=qVkljuc && pVkljuc != -1 && qVkljuc != -1) 
            rezultat[stRezultatov][0] = tmp->p;
            rezultat[stRezultatov][1] = tmp->q;
            stRezultatov++;

            int prvi = min(pVkljuc,qVkljuc);
            int drugi = max(pVkljuc,qVkljuc);
            // prestavimo drugi seznam v prvega (seznama združimo)
            for(int i = 0; i <= dolzVkljuc[drugi]; i++)
            {
                vkljucenost[prvi][dolzVkljuc[prvi]] = vkljucenost[drugi][i];
                dolzVkljuc[prvi]++;
            }
            dolzVkljuc[drugi] = -1; // spraznemo drugi seznam
        } else if((pVkljuc != -1 && qVkljuc == -1) || (pVkljuc == -1 && qVkljuc != -1)) 
        {
            rezultat[stRezultatov][0] = tmp->p;
            rezultat[stRezultatov][1] = tmp->q;
            stRezultatov++;

            if(pVkljuc == -1)
            {
                vkljucenost[qVkljuc][dolzVkljuc[qVkljuc]] = tmp->p;
                dolzVkljuc[qVkljuc]++;
            } else
            {
                vkljucenost[pVkljuc][dolzVkljuc[pVkljuc]] = tmp->q;
                dolzVkljuc[pVkljuc]++;
            }
        } else 
        {
            rezultat[stRezultatov][0] = tmp->p;
            rezultat[stRezultatov][1] = tmp->q;
            stRezultatov++;

            int prviPrazen = 0; 
            while(dolzVkljuc[prviPrazen] > -1)
            {
                prviPrazen++;
            }
            dolzVkljuc[prviPrazen] = 2;
            vkljucenost[prviPrazen][0]=tmp->p;
            vkljucenost[prviPrazen][1]=tmp->q;
        }


        tmp=tmp->next;
    }

    //destruction
    delete[] dolzVkljuc;
    for(int i = 0; i < (dimenzijaMatr/2); i++)
    {
        // error happening here!!!
        delete[] vkljucenost[i];
    }
    delete[] vkljucenost;

    return rezultat;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the `"some code here"` between the two `for` loops. Comment that code and then run. It will run fine. Anyway, you should be using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Use a debugger to isolate the line the error is happenign on.

Comment: @Nawaz Again we see the newbies unfailing ability to only post the code that is correct.

Comment: Instead of using plain C-style arrays, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or `std::array<std::array<int, b>, b / 2>`. The standard containers handle memory management for you; there's no need to call `new` or `delete`. It isn't just easier, but it is also (more or less) the usual and most sensible way to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: when each vector is the same length, vector< vector < int > > is not the best option, matrix would be, boost has a matrix.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm

Comment: debugger shows the error is on the delete[] line in the for loop. Debugger shows that field exists, but as soon as running the delete, show the error window. Will update the question with the debugger screenshot ...

Comment: @CashCow the OP's data structure has unequal width and height. But even then, I'd consider something like `std::vector<int, b * b / 2> a` and access it using `a[ (row * b) + column]` or whatever. Mildly inconvenient, but potentially faster and more efficient. And much simpler than bringing in the entire Boost library!

Comment: a matrix does not need equal width and height, it just requires that all the rows have the same length and they do.
With vector< vector<T> > each inner vector could be of a different size if you want.

Comment: @neuromouse It doesn't matter how many screen shots you attach, the error is in the code you haven't posted. Post some more code! The delete code is correct.

Comment: matrix is a header-only library, so whilst it might be convenient to download the entire boost library, you wouldn't need to build it all.

I used to have my own matrix implementation, based on the C++ FAQ version. It was used in production in 2 jobs where I worked too.

Comment: @neuromouse The code blows up at that line, but that's just a symptom of the actual error which is earlier and in code we can't see. The code you've posted looks fine.

Comment: Entry 6 in your screenshot is 0xCDCDCDCD

Comment: Incidentally, if the actual bug is an access-violation / overflow error, the error would still be there if he used matrix or vector<vector<int> >.

Comment: Posting more code as requested ... (the Kruskal algorithm)

Comment: @neuromouse No chance of understanding all that, and it's incomplete because `Vkljuceno` is missing. You have a bug, it's somewhere in that mess of code. Almost certainly one of your array accesses is going out of bounds. In Java that would throw an exception immediately, in C++ it crashes when you delete the memory.

Comment: Let me reinforce what @Nawaz said: the first thing you need/want to do is forget that you ever even heard of `new`. As a beginner whose just moved from Java to C++, this is roughly equivalent to a child accustomed to throwing snow-balls being handed nuclear weapons to play with.

Comment: @CashCow - entry 6 is not initialized, but I don't think that would cause problems?

Comment: @CashCow Not with a good implementation.  If he has buffer overflow, it should crash immediately, at the site of the overflow.  (It's not required to, and it likely won't if you compile with full optimization, but with the correct options, you're guaranteed a crash with both VC++ and g++.)

Comment: @JerryCoffin There are cases where `new` is necessary, and it should be taught in a beginners course on C++ (but only after `std::vector`).  On the other hand, I've never found a use for `new[]`.  Before `std::vector`, I basically implemented my own (which also separated allocation from initialization---the STL didn't invent anything here).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, at some point, he should learn to deal with `new`, but only with guidance about what to do and when to do it. At least IMO, he's clearly not to that point yet.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It's hard to say whether he's at that point or not.  But my point was really that it's never appropriate to use `new[]` (where as the other `new` has many valid uses).

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too localized" as this is essentially a "debug my code" question.. You are using visual studio so just do a step-by-step debug through it to see where you are performing a bad write.

If you use STL rather than raw pointers it will actually inform you of your bounds error at the time you make it.

You can also use some memory checking tool. They're not free but your company should invest in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the problem was in other code, notwith deleting the nodes. I did not debug the code, but, as the commenters suggested, used std::vector instead of array - first checking that the use of vector has in fact the same efficiency as using arrays.